# Python, I have several ideas on how to solve this, but which should be the correct one?

Tags: python, function, recursion, call

I do not need help with this, it is extremely easy, I need help to decide which of the several ways should I use. Like Do you think I can use recursion? I would need at least an

> if

But, it says

> only function calls

I am thinking of using recursion of course, but I would need an if-else, and yet it says "only function calls"

Consider the following Python function that outputs 4 times a quote from
a famous computer scientist named Brian Kernighan:

```
def print4x() :
  print("Controlling complexity is the essence of programming!")
 print("Controlling complexity is the essence of programming!")
 print("Controlling complexity is the essence of programming!")
 print("Controlling complexity is the essence of programming!")
```

Use this print4x function in a complete Python program that outputs the
Kernighan quote 64 times. Your solution must contain a main function, the
print4x function, and at least one additional function. You should not use
any for loops or while loops or anything like that —

> just function calls!

Simply calling print4x 16 times is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: No, you get me wrong, I am doing this for a student. I have several ways to solve it. But In your opinion which would be valid?

Comment: MendelG: I do not need help with this per se, it is extremely easy, I need help to decide which of the several ways should I use. Like Do you think I can use recursion? I would need at least and if and it says only function calls...

Comment: Green Cloak Guy: It says "Only function calls", so should that rule out recursion or should it not? Since recursion will need at least and if statement...

Comment: Why don't you post a few of the extremely easy solutions and we can see what you've come up with. We don't have the full wording of the problem, it may just mean no "for" but "if" is okay. Seems like this is a question for the teacher.

Comment: @MendelG: please review the StackOverflow stance on homework questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we cannot use loops or condition statements, and can only make use of function, here is my solution.

```
def print4x() :
    print("Controlling complexity is the essence of programming!")
    print("Controlling complexity is the essence of programming!")
    print("Controlling complexity is the essence of programming!")
    print("Controlling complexity is the essence of programming!")

def repeat(num):
    print4x()

numbers = (1, 2)
result = list(map(repeat, numbers))
```

Here we are only making use of functions. Yes there can be an improved code, I am open for suggestion in comments.

---

#### Discussion on language of Question

If we strictly stick to the language of the question, it says **JUST FUNCTION CALLS**

This prevents us from using loops and condition statements which makes it difficult to use recursion.

But some built-in functions also work as loops (like map()). So the question needs to elaborate on what kind of functions are allowed.

Comment: No, you are getting me wrong. I know that, my point is if you think it is valid to use recursion since the problemn says: "Only function calls"

Comment: @AlexisOlceida I have edited the answer, did I get you right this time, does my answer completes your requirements?

Comment: @AlexisOlceida If my answer was helpful, you can accept and upvote the answer to help it reach other people who need it. To accept an answer, you just need to click the tick mark near the answer. Thank you